# How to let locally generated packets pass through PREROUTING chain?

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, iptables

I want locally generated packets to pass through PREROUTING chain bacause I want to use

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d somewebsite.com -j TPROXY --on-port 32794
```

to redirect all packets (generated by a local process) heading to somewesite.com to local port 32794.

Many people suggested this instead:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d somewebsite.com -j REDIRECT --to-ports 32794
```

but **REDIRECT will modify packet header** which I am trying to avoid. I have to use TPROXY, it's the only target type that doesn't modify packet headers.

So what should I do to let locally generated packets pass through PREROUTING chain? Maybe using loopback? But I am not sure whether loopback changes packet headers either...

Comment: Modify kernel's netfilter stack source.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This answer may not be ideal in all cases, but I use a local route (from the proxied IP to your TCP listener's address) to cause locally generated packets to traverse the PREROUTING chain. Assuming your TCP listener accepting on 127.0.01:45265:

    `$ sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 40.114.70.64/32 -p tcp --dport 443 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-ip=127.0.0.1 --on-port=45265`
    `$ sudo ip route add local 40.114.70.64/32 dev lo`

The downside is that the local route affects all packets that match the destination IP, regardless of the destination port.

Comment: @ShawnCarey how does this work, do you know? All the iptables diagrams seem to show no path from local process to PREROUTING.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by marking 'output' packets with a fwmark an adding a loopback-route for those:

*NOTE: This image shows the problem we are facing in a very abstract way. It might not display the traffic-flow in a correct manner!*
[image: https://wiki.superstes.eu/en/latest/_images/nftables_tproxy.png]

**Route**:

```
echo "200 proxy_loopback" > /etc/iproute2/rt_tables.d/proxy.conf
# these need to be configured persistend (maybe use an interface up-hook)
ip rule add fwmark 200 table proxy_loopback
ip -6 rule add fwmark 200 table proxy_loopback
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table proxy_loopback
ip -6 route add local ::/0 dev lo table proxy_loopback
# can be checked using:
ip rule list
ip -6 rule list
ip -d route show table all

# you might need to enable local routing:
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
# you might want to block 127.0.0.1 on non loopback interfaces if you enable it:
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING ! -o lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

**IPTables**:

```
MARK_PROXY=200
MARK_DONE=201
PROXY_UID=13

iptables -t mangle -N PROXY_SESSION
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_SESSION -j MARK --set-mark "$MARK_PROXY"
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_SESSION -j ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j PROXY_SESSION

iptables -t mangle -N PROXY_REDIRECT
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_REDIRECT -p tcp -m mark --mark "$MARK_DONE" -j RETURN 
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_REDIRECT -p tcp -d "$PROXY_EXCLUDE_NET" -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PROXY_REDIRECT -p tcp -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark "$MARK_PROXY/$MARK_PROXY" --on-ip 127.0.0.1 --on-port "$PROXY_PORT" 
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j PROXY_REDIRECT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark "$MARK_DONE" -j CONNMARK --save-mark

iptables -t mangle -N OUTPUT_LOOP
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT_LOOP -m owner --uid-owner "$PROXY_UID" -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT_LOOP -p tcp -m mark --mark "$MARK_DONE" -j RETURN 
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT_LOOP -p tcp -d "$PROXY_EXCLUDE_NET" -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT_LOOP -p tcp -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT_LOOP -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark "$MARK_PROXY"

iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m connmark --mark "$MARK_DONE" -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j OUTPUT_LOOP
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m mark --mark "$MARK_DONE" -j MARK --set-mark 0
```

**Additional information** can be found here:

- [wiki.superstes.eu](https://wiki.superstes.eu/en/latest/1/network/firewall_nftables.html#tproxy)
- [TProxy example using IPTables](https://gist.github.com/superstes/c4fefbf403f61812abf89165d7bc4000)
- [TProxy example using NFTables](https://gist.github.com/superstes/6b7ed764482e4a8a75334f269493ac2e)